# How to verify that auto start option for my android app is enabled or disabled

Tags: android

I want to auto start my android app either at boot time or after installation of app. I have applied following code: (AndroidManifest.xml)

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.javacodegeeks.androidserviceonbootexample"
    android:installLocation="internalOnly"
    >

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_BOOT_COMPLETED"></uses-permission>

    <receiver
        android:name="com.javacodegeeks.androidserviceonbootexample.BroadcastReceiverOnBootComplete"
        android:enabled="true"
        android:exported="false"  android:permission="android.permission.RECEIVE_BOOT_COMPLETED">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.QUICKBOOT_POWERON" />
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
        </intent-filter>
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.PACKAGE_REPLACED" />
            <data android:scheme="package" />
        </intent-filter>
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.PACKAGE_ADDED" />
            <data android:scheme="package" />
        </intent-filter>
    </receiver>

    <service android:name="com.javacodegeeks.androidserviceonbootexample.AndroidServiceStartOnBoot"></service>

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme">

        <activity
            android:name=".MainActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

(MainActivity)

```
       import android.app.Activity;
        import android.content.ComponentName;
        import android.content.Intent;
        import android.os.Build;
        import android.os.Bundle;

        import com.javacodegeeks.androidserviceonbootexample.R;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);

        String manufacturer = "xiaomi";
        if(manufacturer.equalsIgnoreCase(android.os.Build.MANUFACTURER)) {
            //this will open auto start screen where user can enable permission for your app
            Intent intent = new Intent();
            intent.setComponent(new ComponentName("com.miui.securitycenter", "com.miui.permcenter.autostart.AutoStartManagementActivity"));
            startActivity(intent);
        }else if(Build.BRAND.equalsIgnoreCase("Letv")){

            Intent intent = new Intent();
            intent.setComponent(new ComponentName("com.letv.android.letvsafe", "com.letv.android.letvsafe.AutobootManageActivity"));
            startActivity(intent);

        }
        else if(Build.BRAND.equalsIgnoreCase("Honor")){

            Intent intent = new Intent();
            intent.setComponent(new ComponentName("com.huawei.systemmanager", "com.huawei.systemmanager.optimize.process.ProtectActivity"));
            startActivity(intent);

        }
    }
}
```

(OnBootCompleteBroadcastReciever.java)

```
    import android.content.BroadcastReceiver;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class OnBootCompleteBroadcastReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {

    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {

        if (intent.getAction().equalsIgnoreCase(Intent.ACTION_BOOT_COMPLETED)) {
            Toast.makeText(context,"BroadCast",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            Intent serviceIntent = new Intent(context, ServiceStartOnBoot.class);
            serviceIntent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
            context.startService(serviceIntent);
        }

    }


}
```

(ServiceStartOnBoot.java)

```
import android.app.Service;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.IBinder;

public class ServiceStartOnBoot extends Service {

    @Override
    public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate() {
        super.onCreate();
    }
}
```

But the above code don't work. How to check if autostart permission already enabled or not. This code always open autostart permission screen . I want to show this screen only when app is not enabled for autostart.

Comment: Do You Know About These Things Android Allow To this Action . I My Understanding Android Not Allow to do This action

Comment: But how apps like facebook, gmail, whatsapp are allowed for the same? In such apps auto start option is enabled by default, how?

Comment: Any updates on this topic?

Comment: this git repo might be useful. https://github.com/judemanutd/AutoStarter

Answer (score 9):

Some apps like Facebook, Gmail, Whatsapp are whitelisted from manufacturers by default, that means auto start permission will automatically be on for these apps.

For now it's not possible to verify that auto start option is enabled or disabled in our app, but u can ask user for enable it manually only one time (assume when user install the application).

You can redirect user to autostart permission's settings page for enabling your app using following code (tested and working for Oppo, Vivo, Xiomi, Letv, Huawei, and Honor):

```
try {
    Intent intent = new Intent();
    String manufacturer = android.os.Build.MANUFACTURER;
    if ("xiaomi".equalsIgnoreCase(manufacturer)) {
        intent.setComponent(new ComponentName("com.miui.securitycenter", "com.miui.permcenter.autostart.AutoStartManagementActivity"));
    } else if ("oppo".equalsIgnoreCase(manufacturer)) {
        intent.setComponent(new ComponentName("com.coloros.safecenter", "com.coloros.safecenter.permission.startup.StartupAppListActivity"));
    } else if ("vivo".equalsIgnoreCase(manufacturer)) {
        intent.setComponent(new ComponentName("com.vivo.permissionmanager", "com.vivo.permissionmanager.activity.BgStartUpManagerActivity"));
    } else if ("Letv".equalsIgnoreCase(manufacturer)) {
        intent.setComponent(new ComponentName("com.letv.android.letvsafe", "com.letv.android.letvsafe.AutobootManageActivity"));
    } else if ("Honor".equalsIgnoreCase(manufacturer)) {
        intent.setComponent(new ComponentName("com.huawei.systemmanager", "com.huawei.systemmanager.optimize.process.ProtectActivity"));
    }

    List<ResolveInfo> list = getPackageManager().queryIntentActivities(intent, PackageManager.MATCH_DEFAULT_ONLY);
    if  (list.size() > 0) {
        startActivity(intent);
    }
} catch (Exception e) {
    Log.e("exc" , String.valueOf(e));
}
```

Comment: Any updates since 2019? Maybe more manufacturers?

Answer (score 0):

```
var POWER_MANAGER_INTENTS = mutableListOf(
    Intent().setComponent(ComponentName("com.miui.securitycenter", "com.miui.permcenter.autostart.AutoStartManagementActivity")),
    Intent().setComponent(ComponentName("com.letv.android.letvsafe", "com.letv.android.letvsafe.AutobootManageActivity")),
    Intent().setComponent(ComponentName("com.huawei.systemmanager", "com.huawei.systemmanager.optimize.process.ProtectActivity")),
    Intent().setComponent(ComponentName("com.coloros.safecenter", "com.coloros.safecenter.permission.startup.StartupAppListActivity")),
    Intent().setComponent(ComponentName("com.coloros.safecenter", "com.coloros.safecenter.startupapp.StartupAppListActivity")),
    Intent().setComponent(ComponentName("com.oppo.safe", "com.oppo.safe.permission.startup.StartupAppListActivity")),
    Intent().setComponent(ComponentName("com.iqoo.secure", "com.iqoo.secure.ui.phoneoptimize.AddWhiteListActivity")),
    Intent().setComponent(ComponentName("com.iqoo.secure", "com.iqoo.secure.ui.phoneoptimize.BgStartUpManager")),
    Intent().setComponent(ComponentName("com.vivo.permissionmanager", "com.vivo.permissionmanager.activity.BgStartUpManagerActivity")),
    Intent().setComponent(ComponentName("com.asus.mobilemanager", "com.asus.mobilemanager.entry.FunctionActivity")).setData(Uri.parse("mobilemanager://function/entry/AutoStart"))
)
```

Here is more updated manifecturers.